# Group with infinite order

Tags: group-theory

I know that Lagrange theorem for finite group stays true for infinite groups:
if $H\leq G$ : $card(G) = card(H) \times [G:H]$.

How to interpret it for a group G with infinite order?

Many thanks!

Comment: Just the same but with infinite cardinals, but I think this would be equivalent with AC (=Axiom of Choice).

Answer (score 2):

Lagrange's theorem is completely the same for infinite groups.

> Lagrange's theorem: let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Then $$|G|=|H|[G:H]$$

When $G$ is finite, then the statement also says that $|H|$ divides $|G|$. When $G$ is infinite, then Lagrange's theorem tells us what kind of infinity $|G|$ is in relation to the kinds of infinity of $|H|$. In the infinite case it is equivalent to the axiom of choice (see this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory))).

**Addendum:** The infinities of $H$ and $G$ are related via Lagrange's theorem precisely. See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) for more information on how cardinal numbers multiply, and what kinds there are. Also see this [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256352/is-lagranges-theorem-equivalent-to-ac) about the equivalency of Lagrange's theorem an the axiom of choice.

Comment: I've checked the axiom of choice, does it mean that H or G:H might  be infinite?
Can we find out how H infinity relates to G order ?

Comment: I just added some more info.